# Bash echo command not making use of escaped character

Tags: bash, escaping, cygwin, newline, echo

The bash `echo` command isn't using the escaped characters like "\n" and "\t"

```
echo "This is test string\nAnd this is next line"
```

For the above input it displays

```
This is test string\nAnd this is next line
```

So how do I print on the next line?

Comment: Nah, it's a shell programming question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need `echo -e` if you want escaped characters to be expanded:

```
$ echo -e "This is test string\nAnd this is next line"
This is test string 
And this is next line
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$ echo $'This is test string\nAnd this is next line'
This is test string
And this is next line
```

---

**[ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)**

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

Answer (score 6):

The `echo` command varies quite a bit -- some implementations interpret escape characters in their arguments, some don't unless you add the `-e` option... some will print "-e" as part of their output if you try to use it as an option.  If you want predictable results when doing anything nontrivial, use `printf` instead (note that you must explicitly include the ending newline):

```
printf "This is test string\nAnd this is next line\n"
```

I learned this lesson the hard way, when OS X v10.5 came with a version of bash with a builtin `echo` that broke a bunch of my scripts that'd worked just fine under v10.4...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `echo -e` or you can use the `shopt` built-in thusly at the beginning of your script:

```
shopt -s xpg_echo
...
echo "hello world\n"
```