# How to print/echo 'alert' (07) from command prompt

Tags: bash, unix, ascii, echo, control-characters

In python to make a beep I print the control character `07`. For example:

```
>>> print('\x07')
# <beep>
```

Is it possible to do this from the shell? I've been trying things like:

```
david$ echo \x07
x07
david$ echo '\x07'
\x07
david$ echo "\x07"
\x07
```

But just prints it literally. How could this be done, outside of doing something like:

```
$ python -c "print('\x07')"
```

Seems like `printf` works:

```
$ printf '\a'
```

Any way to do this with `echo` as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash echo command not making use of escaped character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802308/bash-echo-command-not-making-use-of-escaped-character)

Comment: @PaulR it's ok, but I think both answers here are much more comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite easy:

```sh
printf "\a"
```

prints the alarm/bell character.

The problem with `echo` is that POSIX says

> If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a  character, the results are implementation-defined.

And, indeed, depending on your shell if using a built-in version (And *which* shell it is), or your OS if using a free standing `echo`, some will interpret backslash escapes by default, some require a specific option (Usually `-e`) to do so, some (`zsh`) depend on what a shell option is set to... it's easier to just use `printf`, which will always behave the same way with respect to escape sequences like `\a`.

Comment: sure I've just found that myself as well (see updated question). Possible with `echo` ?

Comment: @carl.hiass Not portably. Some versions of `echo` support backslash escapes like that, some don't. `printf` always does, making it preferrable.

Answer (score 1):

For Bash, the built-in `echo` command supports escaping:

```
echo -ne '\a'
```

For a POSIX-compliant shell, `printf` is a better option:

```
printf '\a'
```

Or with GNU Core Utilities:

```
/bin/echo -ne '\a'
```

Comment: perfect, thank you. Out of curiosity, how to detect which default shell a specific command prompt is using? `$ echo -e '\a'` works for me!

Comment: @carl.hiass Usually checking for `$0` is enough, but specific tests for each shell may be necessary to cover edge cases, e.g. presence and value of `$BASH_VERSION`, etc.

Comment: Don't check for anything. Just use `printf` everywhere.